# Retrieving Contact List from whatsapp in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, whatsapp

Is it possible to retrieve contacts from contact list who are using whatsapp? if yes then how can we proceed with this?

Comment: Thanks for the response. My question is I just need to filter the contact list who are using whatsapp. So is it possible because I can't find any related knowledge in the given link. Thanks :)

Comment: I have compiled documents at whatsapp developer site .Didn't find any way to fetch contacts.

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaSiddiqui  any updates?